# Why is scanf/printf faster than cin/cout?

Tags: c++, performance

I've made some programs and saw that `scanf` and `printf` are considerably faster than using `cin` and `cout`? Most of my programs clear the execution time limit, mostly 3 seconds or 5 seconds, on online compilers when using `scanf`/`printf` which exceeded the limit while using `cin`/`cout`.

Comment: You say "clear the time limit on online compilers" which makes me think you actually meant to ask why do programs that use scanf/printf *compile* faster than ones that use cin/cout. Is this correct?

Comment: If you care about speed, cid/cout are not your friend. You need to be using more specialist instruments. This is discussed in Effective C++ among others.

Comment: I believe it's also worth noting that if you care about speed and you've determined that your code is not meeting your performance requirements, you should first determine *where* your bottleneck is before attempting to optimize it. If your bottleneck does not involve iostream vs stdio at all, then your energy would be more well spent on other parts of your code.

Comment: @JackAidley: If you read the linked questions you will find cin/cout are as fast as C stdin/stdout if you first take the time to decouple them from the C infrastructure.

Comment: see also this question and answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688763/why-is-istream-ostream-slow