# Why is istream/ostream slow

Tags: c++, performance, ostream, istream

At 50:40 of http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly Andrei Alexandrescu makes a joke about how not efficient/slow istream is.

I had an issue in the past with ostream being slow and fwrite being significantly faster (reducing many seconds when running the main loop once) but I never understood why nor looked into it.

What makes istream and ostream slow in C++? or at least slow compared to other things (like fread/fget, fwrite) which would equally satisfied the needs.

Comment: IIRC the C++ streams have to sync with the C i/o "constructs" if you will (for compatibility reasons). I believe you can make them faster by turning that syncing off (granted you'll have to restrain from doing things like printf afterwards)

Comment: @Borgleader: What C "constructs" would ostream sync to (it was a file output stream not std::out) and why is it slower then C fwrite?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9371717/583833

Comment: @Borgleader: That definitely answers the cin question. +1

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340396/does-the-c-standard-mandate-poor-performance-for-iostreams-or-am-i-just-deali

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Actually, IOStreams don't have to be slow! It is a matter of implementing them in a reasonable way to make them fast, though. Most standard C++ library don't seem to pay too much attention to implement IOStreams. A long time ago when my [CXXRT](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) was still maintained it was about as fast as stdio - when used correctly!

Note that there are few performance traps for users laid out with IOStreams, however.  The following guidelines apply to all IOStream implementations but especially to those which are tailored to be fast:

1. When using `std::cin`, `std::cout`, etc. you need to call `std::sync_with_stdio(false)`! Without this call, any use of the standard stream objects is required to synchronize with C's standard streams. Of course, when using `std::sync_with_stdio(false)` it is assumed that you don't mix `std::cin` with `stdin`, `std::cout` with `stdout`, etc.
2. [Do **not** use `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) as it mandates many unnecessary flushes of any buffer. Likewise, don't set `std::ios_base::unitbuf` or use `std::flush` unnecessarily.
3. When creating your own stream buffers (OK, few users do), make sure they do use an internal buffer! Processing individual characters jumps through multiple conditions and a `virtual` function which makes it hideously slow.

Comment: +1 For pointing out that it's mostly a problem with the implementation, not the library itself. Efficient iostreams implementation is also one of the main concerns in the [C++ Performance Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/18015.html) published by the ISO committee in 2006.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: As it happens, much of the material on performance of IOStreams is based on my contributions :-) (the contributions are not attributed to their respective authors; the contributors are listed on page 6, however).

Answer (score 44):

There are several reasons why [i]ostreams are slow by design:

- **Shared formatting state**: every formatted output operation has to check all formatting state that might have been previously mutated by I/O manipulators. For this reason iostreams are inherently slower than `printf`-like APIs (especially with format string compilation like in Rust or [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#compile-api) that avoid parsing overhead) where all formatting information is local.
- **Uncontrolled use of locales**: all formatting goes through an inefficient locale layer even if you don't want this, for example when writing a JSON file. See [N4412: Shortcomings of iostreams](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4412.html).
- **Inefficient top-level API**: formatting a message with iostreams normally consists of multiple formatting function calls because arguments and I/O manipulators are interleaved with parts of the message. For example, there are three such calls ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/r7j476)) in

  ```cpp
  std::cout << "The answer is " << answer << ".\n";
  ```

  compared to just one ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7sbPro)) in the equivalent `printf` call:

  ```cpp
  printf("The answer is %d.\n", answer);
  ```

  Each of these formatting function invocations has substantial overhead (see above). In replacement-based APIs like `printf` there is little overhead for literal portions of the string.
- **Extra buffering and synchronization**. This can be disabled with `sync_with_stdio(false)` at the cost of poor interoperability with other I/O facilities.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps this can give some idea of what you're dealing with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

unsigned count1(FILE *infile, char c) { 
    int ch;
    unsigned count = 0;

    while (EOF != (ch=getc(infile)))
        if (ch == c)
            ++count;
    return count;
}

unsigned int count2(FILE *infile, char c) { 
    static char buffer[8192];
    int size;
    unsigned int count = 0;

    while (0 < (size = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), infile)))
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            if (buffer[i] == c)
                ++count;
    return count;
}

unsigned count3(std::istream &infile, char c) {    
    return std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile), 
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), c);
}

unsigned count4(std::istream &infile, char c) {    
    return std::count(std::istream_iterator<char>(infile), 
                    std::istream_iterator<char>(), c);
}

unsigned int count5(std::istream &infile, char c) {
    static char buffer[8192];
    unsigned int count = 0;

    while (infile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
        count += std::count(buffer, buffer+infile.gcount(), c);
    count += std::count(buffer, buffer+infile.gcount(), c);
    return count;
}

unsigned count6(std::istream &infile, char c) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    char ch;

    while (infile >> ch)
        if (ch == c)
            ++count;
    return count;
}

template <class F, class T>
void timer(F f, T &t, std::string const &title) { 
    unsigned count;
    clock_t start = clock();
    count = f(t, 'N');
    clock_t stop = clock();
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(30) << title << "\tCount: " << count;
    std::cout << "\tTime: " << double(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
}

int main() {
    char const *name = "equivs2.txt";

    FILE *infile=fopen(name, "r");

    timer(count1, infile, "ignore");

    rewind(infile);
    timer(count1, infile, "using getc");

    rewind(infile);
    timer(count2, infile, "using fread");

    fclose(infile);

    std::ifstream in2(name);
    timer(count3, in2, "ignore");

    in2.clear();
    in2.seekg(0);
    timer(count3, in2, "using streambuf iterators");

    in2.clear();
    in2.seekg(0);
    timer(count4, in2, "using stream iterators");

    in2.clear();
    in2.seekg(0);
    timer(count5, in2, "using istream::read");

    in2.clear();
    in2.seekg(0);
    timer(count6, in2, "using operator>>");

    return 0;
}
```

Running this, I get results like this (with MS VC++):

```
ignore                          Count: 1300     Time: 0.309
using getc                      Count: 1300     Time: 0.308
using fread                     Count: 1300     Time: 0.028
ignore                          Count: 1300     Time: 0.091
using streambuf iterators       Count: 1300     Time: 0.091
using stream iterators          Count: 1300     Time: 0.613
using istream::read             Count: 1300     Time: 0.028
using operator>>                Count: 1300     Time: 0.619
```

and this (with MinGW):

```
ignore                          Count: 1300     Time: 0.052
using getc                      Count: 1300     Time: 0.044
using fread                     Count: 1300     Time: 0.036
ignore                          Count: 1300     Time: 0.068
using streambuf iterators       Count: 1300     Time: 0.068
using stream iterators          Count: 1300     Time: 0.131
using istream::read             Count: 1300     Time: 0.037
using operator>>                Count: 1300     Time: 0.121
```

As we can see in the results, it's not really a matter of iostreams being categorically slow. Rather, a great deal depends on exactly how you use iostreams (and to a lesser extent `FILE *` as well). There's also a pretty substantial variation just between these to implementations.

Nonetheless, the fastest versions with each (`fread` and `istream::read`) are essentially tied. With VC++ `getc` is quite a bit slower than either `istream::read` or and `istreambuf_iterator`.

Bottom line: getting good performance from iostreams requires a little more care than with `FILE *` -- but it's certainly possible. They also give you more options: convenience when you don't care all that much about speed, and performance directly competitive with the best you can get from C-style I/O, with a little extra work.

Comment: Since my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2929159) got rejected: your `istream::read`-version has a bug. The last chunk of characters isn’t checked, [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8376d576889f7628).

Comment: Handy. Also, if you copy count6 to a new count7 with "while (infile.get(ch))" and you'll see that it is twice as fast as operator>> but still twice as slow as getc.

Comment: @NickWestgate: Yeah--no matter how many I add, there are at least three more that could be added. If (for example) another method were faster than anything else, I'd probably add it--but another that's more or less in the middle of the pack just doesn't seem like it's worth bothering...

Comment: Well it would be useful for those (like me) who are comparing the current state of some code to the other options. I'm pretty disappointed that istream::get spends a lot of time entering and exiting critical sections in some single-threaded code I maintain. ; - ) Anyway, thanks for the handy test suite.

Comment: File I/O is inherently noisy on Windows and probably Linux as well due to caching.

Answer (score 1):

While this question is quite old, I'm amazed nobody has mentioned iostream object construction.

That is, whenever you create an STL `iostream` (and other stream variants), if you step into the code, the constructor calls an internal `Init` function. In there, `operator new` is called to create a new `locale` object.
And likewise, is destroyed upon destruction.

This is hideous, IMHO. And certainly contributes to slow object construction/destruction, because memory is being allocated/deallocated using a system lock, at some point.

Further, some of the STL streams allow you to specify an `allocator`, so why is the `locale` created NOT using the specified allocator?

Using streams in a multithreaded environment, you could also imagine the bottleneck imposed by calling `operator new` every time a new stream object is constructed.

Hideous mess if you ask me, as I am finding out myself right now!

Comment: [Karl Knechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel) says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment11835795_9371717): _"(...) This task is almost certainly I/O bound and there is way too much FUD going around about the cost of creating std::string objects in C++ or using <iostream> in and of itself."_

Comment: [Somebody else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable?rq=1#comment81655883_12843784) has exactly the same reasoning....

Comment: The [rationale provided by the llvm project](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#include-iostream-is-forbidden) for never using <iostream> is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

On a similar topic, STL says:  "You can call setvbuf() to enable buffering on stdout."

https://web.archive.org/web/20170329163751/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/642876/std-wcout-is-ten-times-slower-than-wprintf-performance-bug-in-c-library