# Huge speed difference between identical c and c++ programs

Tags: c++, c, performance

I'm very new to c and c++ programming, so I'm starting with the basics.  I wrote identical Fibonacci loop programs for both c and c++ to test relative speed.  I thought they'd be about the same for something so simple, but the c++ version is 60x slower.  All they do is loop through and print the first 14 Fibonacci numbers 10,000 times.  Here is the c version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int c = 0;
    int x, y, z;

    while(c < 10000)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        while(x < 255)
        {
            printf("%d\n", x);
            z = x + y;
            x = y;
            y = z;
        }
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the c++ version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    while(c < 10000)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        while(x < 255)
        {
            cout << x << endl;
            z = x + y;
            x = y;
            y = z;
        }
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote both in notepad++ and compiled them using g++ from the mingw that comes with codeblocks:

```
g++ -o fibc.exe fib.c -s
g++ -o fibcpp.exe fib.cpp -s
```

The executables are very different in size: the c is 8.5KB and the c++ is 784KB! I used powershell to time them:

```
Measure-Command {start-process "C:\Path\fibcpp.exe" -RedirectStandardOutput "C:\Path\cpp.txt" -Wait}
```

The files produced are identical, but the c version took 1 sec and the c++ verison took 60sec! (In fact, putting a loop of 1 million for the c program still only took 13sec). I also wrote the c++ in Visual Studio 17 and compiled it there with an x86 release config.  The program size is now 9.5KB, but the run time is the same as the g++ version: 62sec.  Why is this happening for such a simple program?

Comment: Try to use the same header as the C code in the C++ code. Remove `using namespace std;` and use `printf` instead of `cout` and check again the difference between them. When you run such an experiment you should have the closests codes as you can.

Comment: Try using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` for starters, you don't need to flush every time. Have you tryed to compile with optimizations, like e.g. `-O2`?

Comment: You're not comparing equivalent code.   C++ streams (`std::cout`, etc) are synchronised with their C equivalents by default - which means a performance hit by default.   Try doing `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)` before performing output - then the C++ version will be closer (albeit not completely equivalent) to the C version.   Also, the `endl` stream manipulator flushes the stream buffer, which is not done when supplying a `'\n'` to `printf()`.   Also, benchmarking is usually pointless on unoptimised code.

Comment: could you replace cout with printf?

Comment: @Peter you mean _" when supplying a '\n' to cout"_, don't you?

Comment: @Jabberwocky - I was just pointing out a few differences differences between the allegedly equivalent C and C++ code.     Yeah, but you're right - `printf()` does flush when there is a newline in the format string.

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051948/why-is-stdcout-so-time-consuming?rq=1

Comment: Please also note this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html

Comment: Well, you guys solved my problem in 2 minutes- thank you.  Switching to stdio and printf in the c++ code was everything- the new exe is the same size and performance as the c version.  As you can see, I'm VERY new to this.

Comment: Hi @MrPuzzler, Are you satisfied with the answers? I mean, there was such a massive performance difference! I simply copied your c++ code and my binary is 12.8 kB. while you said yours was 700+ kB. if `iostream` and `cout`s were that big deal in size and performance issue, then why are they extensively used... **I'm puzzled TBH**

Comment: @RC0993: `std::cout << "hi" << 42;` works, whereas `printf` would require correct format. `std::cout` handles locale, ...

Comment: If the difference was truly that big, that would cast serious doubts on your environment for me. You might want to build both the C and C++ code with maximum optimizations to hopefully get a more "fair" comparison.

Comment: @Jarod42 : sure, there'll be a performance impact, but 60x slower, and 90x binary size ? That's a bit extreme don't you think ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: It's indeed sad that, for a language for which lot of people claim its speed and its "don't pay for that you don't use", there is no simple and fast (C++) ways to do I/O. :-/

Comment: Are you running on a toaster? This takes [0.5 seconds](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/670a11b5f7e7fdc0) as is.

Comment: @Jarod42 : sure there is - just use `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`, and use `"\n"` instead of `std::endl`. My point wasn't that though - it was that I've never seen the impact of those specific C++ features be that big (maybe I've been lucky).

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, not [yet](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Even with that, there are still some required overheads (handling locale for example) which is not really in C++ philosophy. `std::cout` is more convenient than performant. (Not an issue for me BTW).

Answer (score 6):

You are benchmarking `printf` vs `cout`, since these are the major bottlenecks in your program.

`printf` is a terribly slow function, but probably still faster than `osteam`, which will have to maintain its own private hell of template meta programming, to keep it as flexible as required by the C++ standard. `cout` is definitely far more flexible and complex than `printf`. More features means slower code.

If you truly want to compare the two languages, drop the print functions and replace them with a dummy function "foo", with external linkage:

```
void foo (int x);
...

while(x < 255)
{
  foo(x);
```

When benchmarking that code with gcc -O3 for x86, I get almost identical code for [C version](https://godbolt.org/z/ChgHBy) and [C++ version](https://godbolt.org/z/dap0O1).

The only notable difference is the "CRT" goo that C++ added at the end of main(). It is calling atexit and various other clean-up that C will do too, but perhaps outside the application code. Still there will always be overhead in C++, because it has to call constructs and clean-up destructors of objects with static storage duration. C doesn't have to do this.

Comment: If you don't include iostream then the two are actually identical (aside from name mangling of `foo`).  The key takeaway is that just _including_ iostream contributes some (small) overhead to your program.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I'd rather suspect that including anything with static storage duration objects creates overhead.

Comment: Template meta programming does not affect execution speed. Things like buffering strategies, flushing, and synchronization do.

Comment: @aschepler All manner of overhead code affects execution speed. Things that can be resolved at compile-time don't, but meta programming almost always means overhead code. And so `ostream` is dreadfully slow.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why C++ `cout` is slow is explained in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/).

> By default, iostream objects and cstdio streams are synchronized (as if this function was called with true as argument).

So by default `cout` is synced with stdio.

Try executing the following to speed up.

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)
```

But be careful, this code will print something you don't expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout << "a\n";
    std::printf("b\n");
    std::cout << "c\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int c = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    while(c < 10000)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        while(x < 255)
        {
            cout << x << '\n';
            z = x + y;
            x = y;
            y = z;
        }
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with basic modern optimizations (`-Os`) gets

```
$ ls -l bin/c?
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jthill jthill 16592 Feb 29 12:47 bin/c1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jthill jthill 17176 Feb 29 12:53 bin/c2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jthill jthill 17088 Feb 29 12:49 bin/c3
$
```

(your C version is `c1`, your C++ version is `c2`, the above C++ version is `c3`).

Averaging the timing for 100 runs each,

```
$ for x in {1..100}; do time bin/c1; done 2>&1 >$scratch | awk '/user/{++n; sub(/0m/,"",$2); tot+=$2}END{print tot/n}'
0.00862
$ for x in {1..100}; do time bin/c2; done 2>&1 >$scratch | awk '/user/{++n; sub(/0m/,"",$2); tot+=$2}END{print tot/n}'
0.0428
$ for x in {1..100}; do time bin/c3; done 2>&1 >$scratch | awk '/user/{++n; sub(/0m/,"",$2); tot+=$2}END{print tot/n}'
0.00743
```

Used properly, C++'s iostreams are *faster* than C's stdio.